# How to store python script data into Django model

Tags: python, django, jinja2

I've already written a script that parses JSON data from a particular url and stores them into a list. After that I'm able to pass that as an argument to be displayed in my template.

My end goal is to display a table on the template from this JSON data (of which I have currently included only one parameter), for which I believe I need to pass that list into a Django Model.

```
def index(request):
    is_cached = ('raw_json' in request.session)
    print(is_cached)

if not is_cached:
    # g = {'starttime': '2014-01-01', 'endtime': '2014-01-02', 'minmagnitude': '5'}
    g=''
    url1 = ul.urlencode(g)
    # print(url1)
    main_api = 'https://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?format=geojson&'
    final_url = main_api + url1
    # print(final_url)
    raw_json = requests.get(final_url).json()
    string_json = json.dumps(raw_json)
    # print(raw_json)
    with open('test.txt', 'w') as file:
        file.write(string_json)

count = raw_json['metadata']['count']
print('Count: ' + str(count))

maglist = []
placelist = []
for cou in range(0, count):
    mag = (raw_json['features'][cou]['properties']['mag'])
    maglist.append(mag)
    # magdict = dict(list(enumerate(maglist)))
    place = (raw_json['features'][cou]['properties']['place'])
    placelist.append(place)
    # placedict = dict(list(enumerate(placelist)))
    # print(placedict)

with open('test2.txt', 'w+') as t1:
    for features in raw_json['features']:
        coordinates = (features['geometry']['coordinates'])
        id = (features['id'])
        t1.write("id: %s \n" % (id))
        t1.write("coordinates: %s \n" % (coordinates))
        # print(singfeature)
        for properties, value in features['properties'].items():
            t1.write("%s : %s \n" % (properties, value))
        # t1.write("\n")
# print (maglist)
args = {'magni': maglist}
print (args)
return render(request, 'earthquake/index.html', args)
```

The template receives this data with a simple for loop as follows:

```
{% block content %}
    {% for item in magni %}
        <p>{{ item }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

To which the result shows up as follows:

[image: resulting JSON table]

As mentioned previously, I need to display a filterable/sortable table with this parameter (along with other parameters too), so that the end-user may view the data as needed.

I'm quite new to Django.

Comment: What should the result look like?

Comment: Apologies for the rough sketch, but this is what it should look like mostly: https://imgur.com/a/uXWKrDQ

Also if it might help you, I'm going to use the geo-json data from this link:

https://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?format=geojson&

Comment: After rendering data to your template, you should loop to display as table instead of paragraph. And then use JavaScript to make is sortable and filterable.

Comment: Thank you Ricky. I shall try what you have suggested and get back to you. Could you suggest some sample JavaScripts that would help me with the sorting and filtering, if you know any?